# USB powered 4G dongle with a Bluetooth interface

Tags: wifi, bluetooth

I'm looking for a USB powered 4G dongle, that allows network connectivity via Bluetooth.  This is for a different, legacy device that doesn't have Wifi. Possibly, the BT aspect may need to be via `RS232`.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: It makes no sense to me, please explain.  What has Bluetooth got to do with 4G?  What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Legacy device (with full operating system, that I deploy applications to) I mentioned has bluetooth, but no internet connectivity. I want to give it access to the internet (via 4G) using a dongle. In this sense the dongle acts like a gateway

Comment: If it is going to be connected to the device via USB, why do you need Bluetooth?

Comment: There are two devices. One has bluetooth, and nothing else. The other device is where this dongle will live.  That second device will provider POWER (only) to this dongle. The dongle provides internet connectivity to the first device.  Honestly, please don't spend any time questioning why I want this architecture. There are very specific reasons for a very specific situation - trust me :)  Thanks